# Meaning of owl:hasValue?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

What is the meaning of an `owl:hasValue` restriction, and how is it different from `owl:allValuesFrom` and `owl:someValuesFrom`?

In an ontology, I want to write an axiom that says, “Every body that has a diploma is literate.”
How can I write this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Different types of restriction classes

Consider an individual x, a class C, a property P, and another individual y.  Then there are a few class expressions that it sounds like you're concerned with:

#### someValuesFrom

An individual x is an element of the class ∃P.C if *some* individual y such that P(x,y) is an element of C.  In Manchester syntax, ∃P.C is written as “P some C”.

#### allValuesFrom

An individual x is an element of the class ∀P.C if *every* every individual y such that P(x,y) is an element of C.  In Manchester syntax ∀P.C is written as “P only C”.

#### hasValue

An individual x is an element of the class =P.y if it's the case that P(x,y).  In Manchester syntax =P.y is written as “P value y”.

### A version for datatype properties and object properies

In OWL, there are object properties that relate individuals to individuals, and datatype properties that relate individuals to literals.  As a result, OWL actually has two types of restrictions for each of the constructions listed above: one for object properties and one for data properties.  The meaning of each of these is laid out formally in [2.2.3 Class Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-direct-semantics-20121211/#Class_Expressions) of the [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language  Direct Semantics (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/) recommendation.

### The diploma axiom

To write an OWL axiom expressing “every person that has a diploma is literate,” you'd need:

- the classes *LiterateThing*, *Person*, *Diploma*
- a property *hasDiploma*

The axiom would be

> (Person ⊓ ∃hasDiploma.Diploma) ⊑ LiterateThing

This says that if an individual is a person, and has some diploma, then they are literate.  In the RDF serialization of OWL (which is where you'd start to see the restriction classes like you mentioned), this looks like in the Protégé OWL editor, and in RDF/XML:

[image: literacy axiom in Protégé]

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://example.org/literacy#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://example.org/literacy"/>
  <owl:Class>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/literacy#LiterateThing"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/literacy#Person"/>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://example.org/literacy#hasDiploma"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:someValuesFrom>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/literacy#Diploma"/>
        </owl:someValuesFrom>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:intersectionOf>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: What is the meaning og Diploma class

Comment: @user3255520 It's just a class whose instances are Diplomas.  It's not strictly necessary here;  we could have just had a property `hasDiploma` and used a restriction like `hasDiploma min 1` or `hasDiploma some owl:Thing`.  Diploma was just another class, much like Person and LiterateThing.

Comment: Is it true that use <owl:equivalentClass rdf:recource="Diploma"/> for <wol:Class rdf:recource="leterace"/> .

Comment: @user3255520 I don't know what you mean by `<wol:Class rdf:recource="leterace"/>`, but we haven't said that `Diploma` is equivalent to anything.  The axiom you wanted to write was "Every person that has a diploma is literate."  A Diploma is a thing that a person can have, in the same way a shirt is something a person can have.

Comment: that is true,but i want to know if Diploma is a class that its instance has Diploma then literacy class is equivalent with Diploma