# Correct usage of owl:someValue?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

If we want to say every thing that has a book is literacy, is this the correct representation in an OWL ontology?

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="#literacy">
  <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:recource="#has"/>
        <owl:someValue rdf:recource="#book"/>
      </owl:restriction>
  </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems related to your earlier question, [Meaning of owl:hasValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21470449/1281433).  There's no property `owl:someValue`, so, the code you've shown is *not* a legal OWL class expression.  I'd *assume* that you were trying to write the OWL version of this axiom:

> Literacy ≡ ∃has.Book (or, in Manchester syntax: Literacy **equivalentTo** (has **some** Book))

This doesn't make sense to me, and I think it might be an issue with the English;  “Literacy” is the state of “being able to read.”  A person who is able to read is *literate*;  they possess the quality of *literacy*.  It would make more sense to talk about the concept LiterateThing, i.e., the class of things which are literate.  If that's what you mean, then you could write the axiom

> Literate ≡ ∃has.Book (or, in Manchester syntax: Literate **equivalentTo** (has **some** Book))

That's an axiom that you can write, but it's a bit surprising to see, because it's not really *true*;  there are lots of literate things out there that don't have a book, and there are plenty of things that have books that aren't literate.  You might be more interested in a subclass axiom, e.g.,

> Person ⊑ ∃has.Nose

which says that every person has a nose.  It would be *incorrect* to say, though, that

> Person ≡ ∃has.Nose

because there are things that have noses that aren't people (e.g., dogs).